# pass variable from javascript function into php array

Tags: javascript, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying to display a PHP array in a JavaScript function.

```
function displayinfo(id){
     var array = [ {{ $infoarrayFromController[id] }} ]; 
     }
```

Here, as the id is supposed to be received from the select option in the form, and the respective information is supposed to be displayed.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to pass the variable into the array.

The error I got:
[image]

Comment: I got that backwards; you can't use the JS variable `id` in a PHP array; PHP processed long before `id` is available. You could convert `$infoarrayFromController` to a JS variable, like `var jsArray = JSON.parse('{{ $infoarrayFromController }}')`, then `jsArray[id]` should work.

Comment: You'd need to send a http request to a php page with the id, and let php build the array and return it as a response.

Comment: As James stated, the best way would be to call a PHP script. You can also use something like this: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer. You can also echo PHP vars in javascript, it depends what is the content of your variable in your example.